# How to connect postgres database with Grails 2.3.4

Tags: postgresql, grails

I'm new to Grails.  I'm trying to connect postgresql 9.0 database server with grails 2.3.4. I have added postgresql-9.0-801.jdbc3.jar file into the lib folder of grails application.When i'm running the application on Intellij editor then getting following error.
Where i'm doing wrong?

```
|Running Grails application Error | 2013-12-08 18:44:55,837 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR pool.ConnectionPool - Unable to create initial connections of pool. Message: Driver:org.postgresql.Driver@7c3b99 returned null for URL:jdbc:postgres://localhost/clientpro Line | Method ->> 303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
| 138 | run in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask | 895 | runTask in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker | 918 | run in '' ^ 662 | run . . in java.lang.Thread Error | 2013-12-08 18:44:55,877 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR pool.ConnectionPool - Unable to create initial connections of pool. Message: Driver:org.postgresql.Driver@1ab5d6d returned null for URL:jdbc:postgres://localhost/clientpro Line | Method ->> 303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
| 138 | run in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask | 895 | runTask in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker | 918 | run in '' ^ 662 | run . . in java.lang.Thread Error | 2013-12-08 18:44:56,160 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR pool.ConnectionPool - Unable to create initial connections of pool. Message: Driver:org.postgresql.Driver@6bf551 returned null for URL:jdbc:postgres://localhost/clientpro Line | Method ->> 303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
| 138 | run in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask | 895 | runTask in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker | 918 | run in '' ^ 662 | run . . in java.lang.Thread Error | 2013-12-08 18:44:56,174 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader - Error initializing the application: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'lobHandlerDetector' while setting bean property 'lobHandler'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'lobHandlerDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Driver:org.postgresql.Driver@6bf551 returned null for URL:jdbc:postgres://localhost/clientpro Message: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'lobHandlerDetector' while setting bean property 'lobHandler'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'lobHandlerDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Driver:org.postgresql.Driver@6bf551 returned null for URL:jdbc:postgres://localhost/clientpro Line | Method ->> 303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
| 138 | run in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask | 895 | runTask in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker | 918 | run in '' ^ 662 | run . . in java.lang.Thread Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'lobHandlerDetector' while setting bean property 'lobHandler'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'lobHandlerDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Driver:org.postgresql.Driver@6bf551 returned null for URL:jdbc:postgres://localhost/clientpro ->> 303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
| 138 | run in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask | 895 | runTask in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker | 918 | run in '' ^ 662 | run . . in java.lang.Thread Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'lobHandlerDetector' while setting bean property 'lobHandler'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'lobHandlerDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Driver:org.postgresql.Driver@6bf551 returned null for URL:jdbc:postgres://localhost/clientpro ->> 303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
| 138 | run in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask | 895 | runTask in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker | 918 | run in '' ^ 662 | run . . in java.lang.Thread Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'lobHandlerDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Driver:org.postgresql.Driver@6bf551 returned null for URL:jdbc:postgres://localhost/clientpro ->> 303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
| 138 | run in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask | 895 | runTask in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker | 918 | run in '' ^ 662 | run . . in java.lang.Thread Caused by MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Driver:org.postgresql.Driver@6bf551 returned null for URL:jdbc:postgres://localhost/clientpro ->> 303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
| 138 | run in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask | 895 | runTask in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker | 918 | run in '' ^ 662 | run . . in java.lang.Thread Caused by SQLException: Driver:org.postgresql.Driver@6bf551 returned null for URL:jdbc:postgres://localhost/clientpro ->> 303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
| 138 | run in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask | 895 | runTask in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker | 918 | run in '' ^ 662 | run . . in java.lang.Thread Error | Forked Grails VM exited with error Process finished with exit code 1
```

DataSource file :-

```
dataSource {
   pooled = true
   driverClassName = "org.postgresql.Driver"
   dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
   username = "postgres"
   password = "password"
}
hibernate {
   cache.use_second_level_cache = true
   cache.use_query_cache = true
   cache.provider_class='org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider'
}
// environment specific settings
environments {
   development {
      dataSource {
         dbCreate = "update"
         url = "jdbc:postgres://localhost/clientpro"
         username = "postgres"
         password = "password"
      }
   }
   test {
      dataSource {
         dbCreate = "update"
         url = "jdbc:postgres://localhost/clientpro"
         username = "postgres"
         password = "password"
      }
   }
   production {
      dataSource {
         dbCreate = "update"
         url = "jdbc:postgres://localhost/clientpro"
         username = "postgres"
         password = "password"
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try with a different prefix:

```
url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost/clientpro"
```

Comment: I can't believe that they have such a stupid configuration mismatch. It worked for me also, but it would made sense to worked for both